# Manga where 2 characters are immortal and try killing each other a lot (boy and girl)

Tags: story-identification, manga, immortality

I can’t remember it well, but it was two characters in the manga (the MCs). One had a horn and they always tried finding ways to die, but they couldn’t. One was a girl and one was a boy. The boy, I think looked like an animal, I’m not too sure. And they turned immortal 'cause this meteor or something hit the Earth and changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it *Killing Me/Killing You*?

> Synopsis: Ever since a meteorite fell, the world has become strange. Two young immortals, Mithia and Youthanasia, are traveling through this crazy world in hopes of finding a way to die.
>
> From: [MangaUpdates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=146862)

Comment: Could you edit your answer to explain why you think that might be the right story? Adding a synopsis and a link to the source of that synopsis would be helpful as well.